# Is it possible to get a key value after DuplicateKeyException in spring?

Tags: spring, exception

I wonder if it is possible to get a key of a value after DuplicateKeyException in spring?

For example like this:

```
    try {
        KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
        getJdbcTemplate().update(
                new PreparedStatementCreator() {
                    @Override
                    public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
                        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(SQL, new String[]{"ID"});
                        ps.setString(1, user.getUSERNAME());
                        ps.setString(2, user.getEMAIL());
                        return ps;
                    }
                },
                keyHolder);

        logger.info("Insert success");
        return (BigDecimal) keyHolder.getKey();
    } catch (DuplicateKeyException dke) {
        logger.info("Insert failed");
        // get key and do sth with it

        return new BigDecimal(-1);
    }
```

Any suggestions here are welcome.

Comment: DuplicateKeyException will only occur, if you update a row and provide a predefined id. So if you set the id inside of the prepared statement, you have to KNOW it. It does not make sense to me, that you want retrieve it, after you provided it building the sql-query..?

Comment: When using an Oracle database you can get DuplicateKeyException. In my case let's assume i have a constraint like this: CONSTRAINT "USER_CON" UNIQUE ("USERNAME", "EMAIL") so when someone sends exactly the same pair of username and email it will cause the error.

Comment: It is quite difficult to see where the problems is, if there is no table structure or constraint definitions. But i have to repeat myself. You will only get DKExceptions, after inserting or updating data. And you can only insert or update data, if you KNOW the data. And if you KNOW the data, you also know the key. And if you know the key, you know, which key is duplicate. Am I right? ;)

Comment: It is insertion of data, so I don't know the key. I get duplication not of the keys but of the values itself that are repeating in a table.

Comment: Ok, so it is about individual unique constraints. Your problem is, that you have multiple unique constraints in one table and you do not know which of these is the one who raised duplicationexception? If you only have one unique constraint in one table it should be clear which one is wrong.

Comment: Ah, yes, then I just need to select with the values that raised duplicationexception and get the key of that row. Thanks for showing the way.

Comment: As stated in my answer it is dirty to read the problematic column from the exception message. You should never trust `toString()` or `getMessage()`. This is far from best-practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see an optimal solution for this problem. Try something like this:

1. *Preselection* - Select all counts of values. (if you have constraint for mail, check whether the mail exists or not. If you have another constraint for name, check whether the name exists or not. (`SELECT COUNT(name) FROM table WHERE name='SOME_NAME'`) You can do this, before or after experiencing a DuplicateKeyException.
2. *Extraction* - Try to extract the column which causes problems from the Exception-Message (this is dirty). In this case, you don't have to execute multiple queries.